# Path traced by a water drop on an ellipsoid

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections

If we have a smooth football in the shape of an ellipsoid, and that water runs down on its sides, can we trace the path of a water drop on it? For a sphere it seems easy because the force tangential to the surface is perpendicular to the radial vector whereas in the case of an ellipsoid it isn't. Any help?